# JavaScript undefined return

Tags: javascript

looking for help. I think it should be answered somewhere but, could not manage to find.

The problem is in random_mf function. After it runs, it returns undefinied value.

Maybe I am using wrong aproach to this at all. Because that function will have to generate the random not the same number each time other functions calls it.

P.S Everything works fine, if I would generate only random key (when if conditions are deleted, and I would only return item value), but it has possibility to be the same .

```
var fact = ['some facts 1','some facts 2', 'some facts 3','some facts 4', ' some facts 6 ', 'facts 7'];
var myth = ['myth1','myht2', 'myht3','myht4' , 'myht5', 'myth6', 'myth 7'];
var gcount = 5;
var points = 0;

function randomGenerator(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function random_mf(){
    var array = myth.concat(fact);
    var randInt = randomGenerator(0, array.length - 1);
    var empty = [];     
    var item = array[randInt];
    var zzz = empty.includes(item);  
    if(zzz == false){
        empty = empty.push(item);
        alert(item + 'item is defined till here');
        alert(empty[0]); // says its undefined
        return new_item = empty[empty.length - 1];
    } else {
        // need to write such function here to repeat all the process.???
    }
}

//When pressed generates random questions 
function start(){
    var question = document.getElementById("p1");
    random_mf();
    question.innerHTML = new_item;
}
//function to check wethear game is complete or not
function game_loop(){
    if(gcount<=0){
        alert("Game ove, you have used all of your guesses");
    } else if(points == 10){
        alert("Thats it. You have finished with 10 pts, in" + gcount + "guesses");
    } else{}
}

//When pressed checks if question is a fact and if it is, addes 1 pts and if it's not gcount-1
// after all the if() chekcs, it will produce new random question. 

function factB(){
        var question = document.getElementById("p1");
        var y = fact.includes(question.textContent);
        if(y == true){
            points++;
            alert("CORRECT ANSWER. You have " + points + "points!!");
        } else {
            gcount--;
            alert("Answer is not correct. You have " + gcount + " guesses left");
        }
        game_loop();
        random_mf();
        question.innerHTML = item;
    }

//When pressed checks if quesition is a myth and if it is, addes 1 pts and if it's not gcount-1
//after all the if() chekcs, it will check if points do not exceed 10 and gcount<0
//then it will produce new random question. 

function mythB(){
        var question = document.getElementById("p1");
        var x = myth.includes(question.textContent);
        if(x == true){
            points++;
            alert("CORRECT ANSWER. You have " + points + "points!!");
        } else {
            gcount--;
            alert("Answer is not correct. You have " + gcount + " guesses left");
        }
        game_loop();
        random_mf();
        question.innerHTML = item;
    }
```

Comment: What should happen if `zzz == false`?

Comment: It means, item is not in empty[], and it should add item to empty[] and return 
 item, to be used in other function.

Comment: The problem may be there : empty = empty.push(item); No need to reassign empty when pushing value in it !

Comment: `empty = empty.push(item);` <-- Array.push work on the array's **reference**, hence you are assigning the result of the `push` method to the original array, which will lead to a numeric value instead of an array. Just remove the left-hand assignment, and you should be fine: `empty.push(item);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push